# Problem with Google Calendar API Java Library

Tags: java

I try to use Google Calendar API Java library, and copy this code from example:

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("abc");
try {
    myService.setUserCredentials("авaea@gmail.com", "1111223");
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

}
```

I downloaded library from source: gdata-client-1.0,  gdata-calendar-2.0, but I got errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:118)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:100)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:555)
    at Test.main(Test.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Where can I do mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps

The mentioned class is not found in the runtime classpath. The mentioned class is [part](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) of [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). So, if you download and put it in the runtime classpath as well, then this error should disappear.